# Laravel resource route blocking routes without parameters

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling to extend a resource restful controller. I have the PostController in which I created a special function getNext() that is supposed to return me the first future post. Now when I add the route it doesn't work unless I add some (useless) router parameter, or change the url completely :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/api'], function() {
  Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
  Route::get('post/next', 'PostController@getNext');
});
-> GET /api/post/next        returns 200 OK with no data whatsoever
// result of 'php artisan route:list | grep next' 
GET|HEAD | api/post/next | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getNext

Route::group(['prefix' => '/api'], function() {
  Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
  Route::get('post/next/{fakeParam?}', 'PostController@getNext');
});
-> GET /api/post/next        returns 200 OK with no data whatsoever
-> GET /api/post/next/YOLO   returns the correct data !!!

Route::group(['prefix' => '/api'], function() {
  Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
  Route::get('omg/next', 'PostController@getNext');
});
-> GET /api/omg/next         returns the correct data!
```

Now I don't know what's wrong in adding a custom route that has no parameter in a resourceful controlller, but maybe you have the answer!

Comment: Did you try to invert the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the order of the routes. A [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) contains within it a route that is `post/{value}` which catches your post/next.

To fix you can flip them round to be

```
  Route::get('post/next', 'PostController@getNext');
  Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

As a general rule put the more specific url's first with the "catch-alls" last.

Comment: This worked, thanks ! An other answer explained me this before, but the answer was deleted and I could not resolve... no idea why